# Does it exist a spinner ActiveX control?

Tags: widget, activex, spinner, wsh, hta

I'm looking for a way to add a [spinner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinner_%28computing%29) control to a form in a Html Application (HTA).

Of course I could build one my self, but tha's not very convenient, especially for such a simple thing.

Is there an activeX control or anything like that already built somewhere in the Windows' repertory of APIs and frameworks?

**Follow up:**
I found the class `System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown` which is exactly what I need. Unfortunately it's a .NET class so I dont think it's usable in my situation.
I wonder if there is a way to embed that in a HTA through COM interface or something.

Comment: Is this "form" a regular HTML `<form>`-element?

Comment: @Teemu, yep, but just so to access the input fields more easily. It's not going to be send via POST, GET or anything. I'll extract the values myself with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the code below to emulate a spinner.

```
<select multiple size="1" id="sel">
    <option value="0">foo</option>
    <option value="1">bar</option>
    <option value="2">baz</option>
</select>
```

To prevent user to pick more than one option:

```
document.getElementById('sel').addEventListener('click',preventMultiselect,false);

function preventMultiselect(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        this.selectedIndex=this.selectedIndex;
    }
    return;
}
```

This works in Quirks-mode too (with "old-style" event-handling).

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I've already used that `multiple size=1` trick in the past. But since what I'm doing is for Windows only, I thought I could use one of those ActiveX controls that IE supports. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any.